# Angularjs: Wait for watchers to kick in

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to wait for a watcher to finish and then execute my task.

If yes how can I know if the watcher is still executing?

Answer (score 0):

Watchers are asynchronous, but you can use events to notify when a task is done. That is, register an event listener before any change happens, and trigger that event at the end of your watcher function.